# How to copy or change database in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, xcode, sqlite

In my app I use 2 sqlite databases, the first just for read and the second for write and read. I copy the databases in the device with this code in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self createCopyOfLolDatabaseIfNeeded];
    [self createCopyOfSaveDatabaseIfNeeded];
}

- (void)createCopyOfLolDatabaseIfNeeded {
    BOOL success; 
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *appDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Lol.db"];
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Lol.db"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appDBPath];
    if (success) {
        return;
    }
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:appDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

- (void)createCopyOfSaveDatabaseIfNeeded {
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *appDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Save.db"];
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Save.db"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appDBPath];
    if (success) {
        return;
    }
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:appDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Then I added the 2 databases in Copy Bundle Resources.

I have 2 problem:
1-If I modify something in Lol.db and raplece it in bundle, when I start the app in the simulator or on device, the app copy the old db and not the new one.
2-The save.db not work, it was copied in the simulator but is "broken", if I manually put it into the folder of the simulator I can use it also after restart but if I reset the simulator and i re-install the app, the save.db does not work.

How can i fix the problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: You should record the time that you extract the database from your bundle and save that time as a user preference. Then in your app include the timestamp of the resource database. Check the timestamps, and if the file already exists in documentsDirectory but the resource version is newer, overwrite the file. My app does exactly this and I'm soooo glad I included this logic.

Comment: I personally create a "configuration" table in my database, with a version number in it. Every time I update the database in the bundle, I manually increment that version number. That way, when the app runs, it checks the version number, and if less than the version in the bundle I either replace or update the database in Documents accordingly.

Comment: @RobP Ok!! Ill try it. And about the save.db? The app copied it but if i open it with Finder i read "An error occurred:  File is not a SQLite 3 database" and the file have zero byte.

Comment: after you call copyItemAtPath:toPath: you need to check the error. Perhaps Save.db is misnamed in your resources or something. (And, did you hit the assert?)

Comment: @RobP the file have the same name, il I copy it manually inside the simulator, work but the first time i install the app, the db was copied wrond (zero byte and eror if I try to open it).